# How to create a Playstation Portable (PSP) Homebrew App

Tags: c++, c, homebrew, playstation-portable

I'm having some trouble starting out with PSP Homebrew. I purchased a PSP 1001 model and successfully hacked it, but I'm having some trouble getting some information about how to start out creating a custom homebrew app.

I want to create an app that mimics the 'TV-B-Gone' - essentially, it just goes through each of the codes for turning TV's off, or on, and throws the code out through the IR reciever on the 1000 model.

I've found information that you can use Javascript, but don't get any REAL native functions, Actionscript, Lua, and C/C++. I know C and C++, and both apparently offer the ability to access all aspects of the hardware.

I was wondering if anyone would have any advice on how to create a homebrew app. I've created some C++/C applications, but am I able to just put those onto my PSP, or is there a sdk or protocol I have to go through?

I've done some looking around, and all of the sites that people recommend are a couple of years old, and most are now owned by different people and don't offer the tutorials anymore.

Also, would anyone know how to code the transmission out through the IR transceiver on PSP?

Thanks a ton guys, I know this is an old topic that not many people are looking into currently, so any help is appreciated.

TL:DR - Does anyone know any good tutorials for starting PSP homebrew app creation in C++ or C, and does anyone know how to send a code out of the IR module on PSP 1000's in C++ or C?

Comment: When you say "hacked" it do you mean: "you are able to access the hardware trough external connection as wire/wifi" or "you are granted access to the internal libraries" ? If you are at library stage , i would recommend finding out which bit system of OS does it have, and from then write /download emulation and go from there what you basically need is an UNIX platform . CIR protocol :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_IR#CIR_and_protocol_implementation  
IrDA : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_Data_Association but you could do it with IR led and baud.

Comment: See [this wiki page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PSP_Programming) for a decent starting point. You'll need to [build the toolchain yourself](https://github.com/pspdev/psptoolchain) as well.

Comment: I think nobody will answer this question here because it's a legal grey area. There were several tutorials for doing this. Also a example to use the IR. But most of them were probably taken down from Sony.